# Better UI for Favorite Tags / Ignored Tags wanted

Tags: feature-request, tags

The tags look so much like elements that you can just drag and drop, and the landing area for the *Favorite Tags* also kinda looks like you can just shuffle them around or drag stuff outta there.

It's happened several times now where I instinctively try to interact with those things by drag and drop, then it doesn't work, and then then remember that oh yeah actually I have to click the "edit" link and type a tag name into the text input that appears.

Also, it would be a "nice to have" if the bunch of tags in there were either sorted or re-orderable.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really need this anymore, after I noticed that you can favorite/ignore tags with the little ★ character that appears on the hover dialog.

This UI was far from obvious and took me years to discover, so I'll leave this here in case it can be helpful for any future readers:

[image: example]